# Recharts — Is there a way to add a padding between the chart and labels for RadarChart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I'm looking at the simple [RadarChart example](http://recharts.org/en-US/examples/SimpleRadarChart) from their website and I would like to add some padding between the labels and the chart itself but there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this.

Can this be done somehow or can someone suggest another chart library I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with CSS

those have `.recharts-polar-angle-axis-tick-value` class, so simply add css on it

```
.recharts-polar-angle-axis-tick-value {
    transform: translateX(-3rem);
}
```

[image]

Comment: But that moves all labels in 1 direction — Chinese and English are overlapping the chart in your image.

Comment: its just an example, you can move it as you want

Comment: I would need to target each label separately somehow then because Math would need to go up say 2rem and Geography would need to go down 2rem. How could I do that?

Comment: using parent nth:child

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it is to use a custom tick and manipulate the x and y values

```js
function renderPolarAngleAxis({ payload, x, y, cx, cy, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Text
      {...rest}
      verticalAnchor="middle"
      y={y + (y - cy) / 2}
      x={x + (x - cx) / 2}
    >
      {payload.value}
    </Text>
  );
}

return (
  <RadarChart data={data}>
   ...
   <PolarAngleAxis tick={props => renderPolarAngleAxis(props)} />
   ...
  </RadarChart>
)
```

Here's the result

[image]